# setState not setting initial value from api before page load

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-redux, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Trying to set initial state of my functional module by calling an API. I read about useState to set initial value and useEffect which runs while rendering the page so my form page get the default values from the api and the user sees the form pre filled.

Now My problem is that when i try to use the api values inside the form in the return(), i do not get the values inside it pre-filled. If i hardcode the values inside the useState({"sor_name": "ani"}), I was able to get the values inside the form. I shortened my code for easy readability.  Here is my code:

```
const UpdateSOR = (props) => {

const [SOR, setSOR] =  useState([]); // Initialized SOR

async function getSOR() {
    const res = await QueryService.getSOR(2).then(
        res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                setSOR(res.data.data.dataItems[0]); // I get the values in the form {"data":{"dataItems":[{"SOR_NAME":"ani"}]}} 
            }
          }
    ).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    getSOR(); // called SOR
  }, []);

return (

     <form className={`${classes.form} ${classes.body}`} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <Row>
                    <Col lg="2" onChange = {(event) => setSelectedSorName(event.target.value)}>
                        <CommonInput
                            id="sor_name"
                            label="SOR Name"
                            defaultValue={SOR.SOR_NAME} // i dont get the value here on initial load. 
                            disabled={false}
                            multiline={false}
                            rows="1" />
                    </Col>
     </Row>
</form>
)
```

Note: This is my functional module tree structure: 
app-->appBar(component)-->SOR(module)--> updateSOR(module)

If user comes directly to updateSOR like this (localhost:3000/edit/updateSOR/2), i want to run the api and get values and fill the form and render to the user directly. I know i could push api values to props directly from previous page which is **SOR**, but doing so only works when user comes to the page from SOR, But if user directly enters the page name with id in end, i need to populate that updateSOR page.

This is my function written in QueryService which gets the data and i am calling in this updateSOR component in useEffect hook to get the data:

```
function getSOR(id) {
    if(id) {
        return axios.get(`${Constants.API_URL}/SOR?id=${id}`);
    } else {
        return axios.get(`${Constants.API_URL}/SOR`);
    }

}
```

This is my CommonInput function.

```
export default function CommonInput(props) {

const classes = useStyles();

    const { id , label,  defaultValue, disabled, multiline, rows } = props;

    return (

        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <InputLabel id={id}>{label}</InputLabel>
            <Input
                defaultValue={defaultValue}
                id={id}
                disabled={disabled}
                multiline={multiline}
                rows={rows}
            />
        </FormControl>

    )

}
```

Comment: when you console.log(res.data.data.dataItems[0])  what do you have ?

Comment: @FarhaniWalid I get a parsed object like this: {ID: 2, SOR_NAME: "ani"}

Comment: try to change this defaultValue={SOR.SOR_NAME} to this defaultValue={SOR && SOR.SOR_NAME}

Comment: @FarhaniWalid Tried but not getting inside form. Is it because the Common Input class in the jsx before SOR_NAME. I import it in Update SOR. I have updated the question to display <Common Input />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to understand the problem, you need to first understand how `useEffect` works. According to the [React Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

> The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen.

The asynchronous call you are making in `useEffect` to get data is executed *after* your component is rendered for the first time. Therefore, your component renders with the initial state, which is empty. Once the network call completes, `setSOR` is called, triggering a re-render with the new state.

One solution is to provide a return condition for the unresolved state before your return. This can simply be `return false` if you don't want to render anything, or some sort of loading indicator.

**Example**: *(I left out some of your code to highlight the concept)*

```
function UpdateSOR() {
  const [SOR, setSOR] = useState(); // default to undefined state.

  useEffect(() => {
    QueryService.getSOR(2).then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setSOR(res.data.data.dataItems[0]);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (!SOR) return false; // Render nothing, <p>Loading...</p>, etc.

  return <p>{SOR.SOR_NAME}</p>
}
```

Comment: In my case, the setSOR do not render the page again. I checked on console log right before return(). It prints two times. one is empty and the other time when network request completes at that time which give Sor values but the page do not get updated.

Comment: Also one thing I noticed that if i write {SOR.SOR_NAME} in return , I am able to get it on the page but not inside the form value fields. only when i hardcode the values inside the setState({'SOR_NAME': 'ani'}), it comes inside the form Fields

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the response data correctly? If it works when you hardcode the data, then you must not be referencing it on the response correctly.

Comment: I am setting the response correctly but what i feel is that the FormControl material UI Api which i am using is undefined for the first render. And when we get the async response, even though it gets the data but while re rendering the, the default value is still empty.